# Can't get html5 download to work programmatically in Firefox(Works on Safari, IE, Opera, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, download

```
    onDownload: function() {
        var element = document.createElement("a");
        element.setAttribute("href", "/metadata/rest/swagger?namespace=" + this.namespace);
        element.click();
    },
```

Add a download function to a button. But it doesn't work in Firefox.(Works on Safari, IE, Opera, Chromes)

After changing the code in following way:

Create  anchor (<a>) in the html page, make it hidden and give  an id before. Get the element by id.  Set the href attribute

```
onDownload: function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("download");
        element.setAttribute("href", "/metadata/rest/swagger?namespace=" + this.namespace);
        element.click();
},
```

It works on all the browsers mentioned. Why?

Comment: Most likely Firefox simply refuses to execute the click method on an element that is not even part of the DOM … So try and insert it into the DOM before.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

[createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#Browser_compatibility)

> Doesn't conform to the DOM spec for XUL and XHTML documents: localName and namespaceURI are not set to null on the created element.

Though, I'm not fully convinced, you may use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead:

```
var element = document.createElementNS(this.namespace, 'a');
```

This post might not fully answer, but I hope you'll get some help to go through. Just trying to help if you can find it useful for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use HTML5 `download` attribute.

> ```
> <a href="/path/to/file" download>
> ```

- For more about the HTML5 `download` attribute you may read [Anchor element - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)
- For browser support check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility)

You can change the href value accordingly using javascript.